# What are the errata for Swords & Wizardry Complete, 3rd Printing?

Tags: errata, swords-and-wizardry

I just received a copy of S&W Complete, 3rd Printing. I've found a few minor errors, and I was wondering what errors have been noticed already for this edition?

I'm especially interested in identifying errors that may lead to confusion or substantial divergence from the intent during play—if there are any—not a total catalogue of typographical errors whose meaning ought to be obvious.

So far I've only found one error in the first category: The Ranger's advancement table incorrectly lists their Hit Die as a d6 (p23), when it is marked earlier as a d8 (p22, consistent with Fighters and the 2nd printing text).

Comment: Would Swords and Wizardry 4th printing be useful to you?

Comment: Sure. Do you mean Core or Complete? If there are known errata from any edition, it's possible 3rd printing of Complete might have inherited them.